# Android Async Map Parameter

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to write an async task in android. I want to pass a parameter that is a dictionary. How would I change the method signature and access the parameter in the doInBackground method?

```
private class AsyncMapPass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
     protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return null;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simply:

```
private class AsyncMapPass extends AsyncTask<Dictionary, String, String>
{ 
    protected String doInBackground(Dictionary... params) 
    {
        // The params parameter can be accessed like an array
        // So you can pass as many Dictionary objects as needed
        Dictionary d0 = params[0];
        Dictionary d1 = params[1];
        ...
        ...
        return null;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that `Dictionary` is an abstract class, so the objects you pass in the `execute*()` method should be concrete subclass instances.